Powershell changes the return datatype
When I run a compare operation on $certificateFromIssuer within Get-IssuedCertificate I get the proper output.
$certificateFromIssuer.NotAfter -lt $today
The above works as expected.
However, when $certificateFromIssuer is returned to DeleteExpiredCertificates I get the following error.

Cannot compare "@{NotAfter=8/28/2025 5:25:53 PM}" to "8/29/2024 2:56:25 PM" because the objects are not the same type or the object "@{NotAfter=8/28/2025 5:25:53 PM}" does not implement "IComparable".

Here's my full code:
function Get-IssuedCertificates {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $issuer        
    )
    
    $certificates = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My
    $certificatesFromIssuer = $certificates | Where-Object { $_.Issuer -like "*$issuer*" }

    if ($certificatesFromIssuer) {
        return ,$certificatesFromIssuer #| Format-Table -Property Subject, Issuer, Thumbprint, NotAfter

    } else {
        Write-Output "No certificates found from issuer: $issuer"
        return @()
    }
}

function DeleteExpiredCertificates {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $expiredCertificates
    )
    $today = Get-Date
    if(($expiredCertificates | Select-Object -Property NotAfter) -lt $today) {

        Write-Host "Certificate expired on: $($expiredCertificates | Select-Object -Property NotAfter)"
    }
}
DeleteExpiredCertificates -expiredCertificates $(Get-IssuedCertificates -issuer Dexter)

Notice that, in the Delete function, I have to use $expiredCertificates | Select-Object -Property NotAfter because $expiredCertificates.NotAfter seems to return empty value which is also something I'd like to understand.
I'm expecting to understand why the datatype changes when a variable is returned from a function to another.

The main issue with your code is that you're trying to compare an array of objects with a property named NotAfter (this is the output from Select-Object NotAfter) with a DateTime instance. You just need a loop and get rid of Select-Object, you can use dot notation to reference a property value. Also note that [datetime]::Today and Get-Date are not the same, Get-Date is [datetime]::Now.
function DeleteExpiredCertificates {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [X509Certificate[]] $ExpiredCertificates
    )

    $today = [datetime]::Today
    foreach ($cert in $ExpiredCertificates) {
        if ($cert.NotAfter -lt $today) {
            Write-Host "Certificate expired on: $($cert.NotAfter)"
        }
    }
}

If you want your functions to be more PowerShell like, you can have your DeleteExpiredCertificates take values from pipeline, so something like:
function Get-IssuedCertificates {
    [OutputType([X509Certificate])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Issuer
    )

    $certificatesFromIssuer = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My |
        Where-Object { $_.Issuer -like "*$Issuer*" }

    if ($certificatesFromIssuer) {
        return $certificatesFromIssuer
    }

    Write-Error "No certificates found from issuer: $Issuer"
}

function DeleteExpiredCertificates {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [X509Certificate] $ExpiredCertificate
    )

    begin { $today = [datetime]::Today }
    process {
        if ($ExpiredCertificate.NotAfter -lt $today) {
            Write-Host "Certificate expired on: $($ExpiredCertificate.NotAfter)"
        }
    }
}

And then you can pipe the output from one command to the other command:
Get-IssuedCertificates Dexter | DeleteExpiredCertificates


The pipeline expression ...| Select-Object -Property NotAfter will create new objects with a NotAfter property attached, copied from each of the input objects.
But that's not the problem you'll want to address first :)
Since Get-IssuedCertificates is designed to return multiple certificates, you'll want to refactor the deletion command to work with multiple certificates - to facilitate passing either 1 or multiple certificates via either the pipeline (... |DeleteExpiredCertificates) or as an explicitly bound variable (like you currently are), make the following changes:

Declare the $ExpiredCertificates parameter as an array-type
Set the ValueFromPipeline flag in the [Parameter()] decorator
Move the main body code into a process { ... } block and make sure to loop over (or pipe) the input values

function DeleteExpiredCertificates {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [X509Certificate[]]$ExpiredCertificates
    )
    begin {
      $today = Get-Date
    }

    process {
      $ExpiredCertificates |Where-Object { $_.NotAfter -lt $today } |ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Certificate with thumbprint '($_.Thumbprint)' expired on: $($_.NotAfter)"
      }
    }
}

Now you can do both:
Get-IssuedCertificates -Issuer dexter |DeleteExpiredCertificates

... and:
$oldCerts = Get-IssuedCertificates -Issuer dexter
DeleteExpiredCertificates -ExpiredCertificates $oldCerts
# or 
DeleteExpiredCertificates -ExpiredCertificates (Get-IssuedCertificates -Issuer dexter)

For more information about the begin { ... } and process { ... } blocks and how they behave in relation to the pipeline, see the about_Functions_Advanced_Methods help topic
